# A word meaning a lover of poetry

Tags: single-word-requests

...equally useful would be a "poetry expert" (who could be presumed to be a lover of the subject).  Linguaphile, of course, jumps to mind, but I'm looking for something that is specific to poetry, not just language in general. Thanks.

Comment: OED does actually list **poetolatry** *- worship or immoderate veneration **of poets***. But I don't see anything in that general area for veneration of their *literary output*.

Comment: If you're willing to accept novel coinings, I think ***rhapsophile*** has a certain mellifluousness....

Comment: It's certainly nicer-sounding than **poiesiphile**.

Comment: @DanBron mellifluosity

Comment: @Mitch I originally wanted to say "*melifluity*" but the dictionary gave me no warrant and my poetic license expired last week.

Comment: @DanBron dictionaries, pfft. I never studied law so I need not worry bout the law of gravity.

Comment: I think your best bet is a *poet-lover*. Also, [*poetophile*](https://www.google.ca/search?q=linguaphile&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=j8KvVYzgJMuXyASCobnwCQ#safe=off&tbm=bks&q=poetophile) appears in a very few books.

Comment: Some wag once said, "There are thousands of people who write poetry, and hundreds who read it." So maybe *poet* works here? ^_^

Answer (score -1):

**[metrophile:](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/metrophile)** sb with sexuoeroticism linked to poetry

Comment: A metrophile is literally a lover of cities, but it has come to mean a lover of trains, from the nickname "metro" for metropolitan transport.  You've taken a definition from freedictionary.com (without attribution).  Are you sure you haven't hit an outlier?

Comment: Where does it say so ?

Comment: @deadrat that is not the case (i.e. lover of cities). *metro-* (of Greek derivation) means "relating to poetic metre" and *-phile* (also of Greek derivation)  means "lover (of something)". It is a plausible combination, if highly unusual.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен Point taken.  Etymologically, a lover of cities would be "metropoliphile."  But poetic meter isn't quite poetry, and the word would probably be "metroniphile," unless you wanted to mix Latin and Greek roots.    In any case, "metrophile" is taken.

Answer (score -3):

that could be simple

I read

plato said  "I'm a philosopher, a lover of wisdom"

in the magic tree house # 16

a lover of poetry = poet ???

Comment: Please clean up your answer. It is unclearly formatted. Also, it is unlikely that *poet* is the desired answer, as you don't have to write poetry to appreciate it.